# Make html submit better clickable when using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having like a little game on my page with a moving submit button. The button moves to a random position with jQuery every 700 milliseconds but I have a problem that almost 20 times out of 1 when you hit the button it is just focusing the button and not submitting. I have tried added autofocus but that wasn't working either. It is easy to hit the button but it won't submit most of the time.

Any solution to this?

Comment: Any code to this? Increase the `timeout()` duration, may be?

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle/plunkr/codepen to demonstrate your issue.  Also please provide your implementation.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Show effort and code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your user probably doesn't have enough time to release their mouse button before the button disappears. Instead of executing something on the `submit` event try executing it on `mousedown`.